# Pdf Viewer shows only white screen when clicked

Tags: android

I have tried to read a file from the storage. I used **com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1** this library for displaying  pdf in my app from the storage but it shows white screen only 
code is here

```
public class pdfview extends Activity {

PDFView pdfview1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.pdfreader);
    pdfview1 = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "android" + "/" + "Data" + "/" + "FolderName" + "/" + "example.pdf";

    pdfview1.fromFile(new File(path))
            .defaultPage(0)
            .spacing(10)
            .load();
}

}
```

I don't known why its shows only white screen. 
XML FIle

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/balc">


    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

</com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>
```

Comment: are you given stroage permission

Comment: Yes i have given storage permission. PDF is open in default pdf viewer perfectly but i want my own pdf viewer.

Comment: Please show the xml file